# The content of the content_for does not get rendered inside before </head> but it renders before </body>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application.html.erb file that I am trying to render a block from a content_for that described in another file. When I place the <%= yield :template_css_stylesheet_pack_tags %> right before "/head" tag to render last, it does not get rendered, but when I place the yield right before the "/body" tag it renders.

The reason I need to place this right before the /head is to prevent flashing error that occurs. What happens is when a page load something overrides this css styling and cause a flashing issue.

Here is my navigation file that the content_for is located:

_nav.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :template_css_stylesheet_pack_tags do %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'stylesheets/navigation', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<% end %>
```

and here is the application.html.erb I need to place the yield in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'stylesheets/vendors', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'stylesheets/globals', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    
    <%= yield :extra_header_tags %>
    <%= yield :template_css_stylesheet_pack_tags %>
  </head>

  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidebar" data-controller="<%= controller_name %>" data-action-name="<%= action_name %>">
    <%= render partial:"shared/theme" %>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header aria-label="PMP AWARE Header" class="site-header">
        <%= render 'layouts/google_analytics_body' %>
        <a href="#content" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip Navigation</a>

        <% if flash[:error] %>
          <a href="#flash_error_container" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip to list of errors.</a>
        <% end %>

        <% if flash[:alert] %>
          <a href="#flash_error_container" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip to list of warnings.</a>
        <% end %>

        <!-- Your timezone is <%= Time.zone %> -->
        <!-- <%= "Ruby Version is #{RUBY_VERSION}" if Rails.env =~ /test|development/ %> -->
        <%= render partial: "shared/session_timeout" %>
        <%= render partial: "shared/nav" %>
      </header>
      <div role="main" id="content" class="container container--main">
        <%= render partial: "shared/branding_and_breadcrumbs" %>
        <%= render partial:"shared/flash" %>
        <%= render partial: "shared/tabbed_navigation" %>
        
        <%= yield %>
        
      </div>
      current_user&.needs_punished?  %>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: stylesheet link tags need to be within the head section. There is no getting round that.

Comment: You have some garbage left in there - `current_user&.needs_punished?  %>`

Comment: If you need a different stylesheet for a different view but that view will always use the same different stylesheet then use a different layout specifically for the controller that renders that view